# No conecta a firebase V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

Estoy tratando de integrar firebase a un proyecto que fue creado hace tiempo para implementar crashlytics ya que últimamente este se ha venido deteniendo, pero al sincronizar con firebase este no lo hace ni desde mi emulador ni de mi telefono, el logcat siempre me genera esto:

```
   V/FA: onActivityCreated
   V/FA: App measurement collection enabled
   V/FA: App measurement enabled for app package, google app id: con.orca.smart, 1:294578423046:android:302b7bdc48048b049cca87
   V/FA: Persisting first open: 1599229749019
   V/FA: App measurement setting deferred collection: false
   V/FA: Checking service availability
   V/FA: Service available
   V/FA: Connecting to remote service
   V/FA: Detected application was in foreground
   V/FA: Session started, time: 3457503
   V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
   V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
   V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
   V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 3457222
   V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
   V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
   V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 8
   V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 2709
   V/FA: Activity paused, time: 3459938
   V/FA: onActivityCreated
   V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 3460292
   V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Como ven la ultima respuesta que me arroja es `V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service` estuve buscando en internet y comentan que los V/FA no son mensaje de error, pero Por que no me sincroniza y siempre me arroja este resultado

**Actualización**
En buscar el "Cause by" me arroga lo siguiente

```
I/zygote: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/con.orca.smart-UAhy7MRsDM6uL3o3ZL6Nfw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/con.orca.smart-UAhy7MRsDM6uL3o3ZL6Nfw==/lib/x86, /data/app/con.orca.smart-UAhy7MRsDM6uL3o3ZL6Nfw==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
I/zygote: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/con.orca.smart-UAhy7MRsDM6uL3o3ZL6Nfw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/con.orca.smart-UAhy7MRsDM6uL3o3ZL6Nfw==/lib/x86, /data/app/con.orca.smart-UAhy7MRsDM6uL3o3ZL6Nfw==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
I/zygote: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/con.orca.smart-UAhy7MRsDM6uL3o3ZL6Nfw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/con.orca.smart-UAhy7MRsDM6uL3o3ZL6Nfw==/lib/x86, /data/app/con.orca.smart-UAhy7MRsDM6uL3o3ZL6Nfw==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
```

Comment: Busca un texto en el LogCat que inicie como "Caused by" por favor

Comment: Ya lo busque y agrege en la pregunta